# First API call returns proper JSON object however I cannot pull values out of it

Tags: ajax

The API call give a JSON object in the console with responseText. However when I use the object to pull data I get undefined. I do not know what I did wrong. I did read It could be i need HTTPS and not HTTP.

[image]

In the picture, `undefined` corresponds to console.log (datay.main) (main is a key in the JSON object, but console.log (datay) DOES return the JSON object.

```
 let yO = new XMLHttpRequest();
 yO.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
 q=London&appid=a11662929a9ec4f95e189d620d00c4b3&units=metric" )
 yO.onload = function(){
 let data = yO.responseText;
 let datay = JSON.parse(data);

 console.log(datay.main)

 }
 yO.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you added 2 spaces by mistake on the URL `...weather?<space><space>q=London...`, everything else works just fine.

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=a11662929a9ec4f95e189d620d00c4b3&units=metric");
xhr.onload = function(){
    let data = xhr.responseText;
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    
    // Check for errors
    if (data.cod != 200) {
        console.error(data.message);
    }
    
    // No errors
    else {
        console.log(data.main);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```